# Excel VBA Custom dialog box cancel button code

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dialog box pop up with radio buttons, the radio buttons currently run macros. However, once I have the dialog box pop I can't close it. I have added a cancel button. The code is below

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Cmd_Cancel
End Sub
```

How can I get my dialog box to close by pressing the cancel button?

Comment: it´s the dialogue box a form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my form I used a Cancel button with the below code for it

`btnCancel` is the `(Name)` of the button

```
Private Sub btnCancel_Click()

    Unload Form_Form1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want. The keyword "Me" is the actual instance of the Form-Object. Hide it and its still in the memory. Or unload it to kill it:
When it's only hidden you can show it again with .show (from another piece of code...)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Me.Hide
    Unload Me
End Sub
```